# How to prove this formula about complex variables?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading the book "Complex Variables and the Laplace Transform for Engineers"

The exercise 4-26 is as follows.

Let C be a counterclockwise circular contour of radius A < 1 centered at the point s=1.

Prove that

$ \int_C \frac{\log |s|}{s-1} ds = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{-1} \frac{A\sin \theta}{\sqrt{1+2A\cos \theta + A^2}}d\theta$

First, The left side becomes purely imaginary value by using $ s-1 = Ae^{j\theta}$.

And
$ds = jAe^{j\theta} d\theta$

Then,

$ \int_C \frac{\log |s|}{s-1} ds= j\int_0^{2\pi} \log|1+Ae^{j\theta}|d\theta$

I think it doesn't make sense.

Second, I can't find any clue to change the logarithm to trigonometric function.

Can somebody give me some advice on this problem?

Comment: $\int_C \frac{\log |s|}{s-1} ds= i\int_0^{2\pi} \log|1+A e^{i\theta}|d\theta$